# Vuetify v-autocomplete showing [object Object] as initial value (before loading)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

My "Estado" `v-autocomplete` shows text `[object Object]` as an initial value (placeholder).

But after loading it (takes about 4 seconds), everything works normally, the placeholder disappears and I the states are displayed.

I'm using Vuetify for FrontEnd, and here's my code snippet:

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="ma-3"
  >
    <div class="content">
      <template>
        <v-card
          :class="{ 'card-success': cadastro, 'card-warn': !cadastro}"
          style="min-height: 60vh"
        >
          <h4
            v-if="!cadastro"
            slot="header"
            class="card-title text-center"
          >
            Edição de Agroindústria
          </h4>
          <h4
            v-else
            slot="header"
            class="card-title text-center"
          >
            Cadastro de Agroindústria
          </h4>
          <div class="clearfix" />
          <div
            v-if="loading"
            style="height: 60vh"
          >
            <v-row
              class="fill-height ma-2 flex-column"
              align="center"
              justify="center"
            >
              <v-progress-circular
                :size="70"
                color="primary"
                indeterminate
              />
            </v-row>
          </div>
          <div v-if="!loading">
            <v-form
              id="form"
              ref="form"
              v-model="valid"
              class="pa-3"
              lazy-validation
              @submit.prevent="updateProfile"
            >
              <v-card>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-card-title
                    class="headline mx-auto"
                  >
                    Dados Pessoais
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-row
                    v-if="!loading"
                    class="pa-3"
                  >
                    <!-- <v-col
                      cols="12"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.Nome"
                        label="Nome *"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                      />
                    </v-col> -->
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.nomeFantasia"
                        label="Nome Fantasia *"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.razaoSocial"
                        label="Razão Social *"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.porte"
                        label="Porte *"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.cnpj"
                        v-mask="maskCpf"
                        label="CNPJ *"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                        return-masked-value
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-autocomplete
                        v-model="form.estado"
                        label="Estado *"
                        :items="estado"
                        :rules="requiredRules"      //HERE'S WHERE THE ISSUE COMPONENT
                        item-text="Nome"
                        item-value="CodEstado"
                        @change="changeCidade"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-autocomplete
                        v-model="form.cidade"
                        label="Cidade *"
                        :loading="loadingCidades"
                        :items="cidade"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                        item-text="Nome"
                        item-value="CodCidade"
                        :disabled="disableCidade"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="4"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.logradouro"
                        label="Logradouro"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="2"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.numero"
                        label="Numero"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.bairro"
                        label="Bairro *"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.complemento"
                        label="Complemento"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.cep"
                        v-mask="maskCep"
                        :rules="requiredRules"
                        label="CEP *"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.email"
                        :rules="emailRules"
                        label="E-mail"
                        type="email"
                        return-masked-value
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="3"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.telRes"
                        v-mask="maskTelRes"
                        :rules="telRules"
                        label="Telefone Fixo"
                        type="tel"
                        return-masked-value
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="3"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.telCel"
                        v-mask="maskTelCel"
                        :rules="telRules"
                        label="Telefone Celular"
                        type="tel"
                        return-masked-value
                      />
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-card>
              <!-- <v-card>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-card-title
                    class="headline mx-auto"
                  >
                    Dados Técnicos
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-row
                    v-if="!loading"
                    class="pa-3"
                  >
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.captacao"
                        label="Captação"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                    >
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="form.fornecedores"
                        label="Fornecedores"
                      />
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-card> -->
              <v-btn
                type="submit"
                :disabled="salvando"
                :loading="salvando"
                :color="!$route.params.CodPessoa ? 'success' : 'warning'"
                form="form"
              >
                {{ btnNome }}
              </v-btn>

              <router-link
                :disabled="salvando"
                to="listar-agroindustrias"
              >
                <v-btn
                  :disabled="salvando"
                  color="error"
                  class="ml-3"
                >
                  Cancelar
                </v-btn>
              </router-link>
            </v-form>
          </div>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </div>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        salvando: false,
        loading: true,
        loadingCidades: false,
        maskCpf: '##.###.###/####-##',
        maskTelRes: '(##) ####-####',
        maskTelCel: '(##) # ####-####',
        maskCep: '#####-###',
        emailRules: [v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'E-mail invalido'],
        telRules: [v => (!v || v.length === 0 || v.length >= 10) || '* Número inválido'],
        requiredRules: [v => !!v || '* Obrigatório'],
        valid: null,
        disableCidade: true,
        primeiroAcesso: '',
        btnNome: !this.$route.params.CodPessoa ? 'Salvar' : 'Salvar Alterações',
        form: {
          codPessoa: null, // codigo da agroindústria
          nomeFantasia: '',
          razaoSocial: '',
          porte: '',
          cnpj: '',
          estado: 0,
          cidade: 0,
          logradouro: '',
          numero: '',
          bairro: '',
          complemento: '',
          cep: '',
          telRes: '',
          telCel: '',
          email: '',
          // captacao: '',
          // fornecedores: '',
        },
        estado: [{ nome: 'Carregando', CodEstado: 0 }],
        cidade: [],
        cadastro: this.$route.params.CodPessoa === 0 ? 1 : 0,
      }
    },
    created () {
      // console.log(this.$route.params.CodAgroindustria)
      if (this.$route.params.CodPessoa === undefined) {
        // console.log('Indefinido')
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Listar Agroindustrias' })
      } else if (this.$route.params.CodPessoa !== 0) {
        // console.log('edicao')
        this.form.codPessoa = this.$route.params.CodPessoa
        this.formDados()
      } else {
        // console.log('cadastro')
        this.loadNewForm()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      loadNewForm () {
        if (this.$route.params.NomeFantasia !== 'undefined') {
          this.form.nomeFantasia = this.$route.params.NomeFantasia
        }
        if (this.$route.params.Cnpj !== 'undefined') {
          this.form.cnpj = this.$route.params.Cnpj
        }
        if (this.$route.params.primeiroAcesso === 1) {
          this.primeiroAcesso = 1
        } else {
          this.primeiroAcesso = 0
        }
        this.loading = false
        this.loadEstado()
      },
      updateProfile () {
        this.$refs.form.validate()
        if (!this.valid) {
          this.Swal.fire('Atenção', 'Preencha os itens obrigatórios sinalizados com ("*").', 'warning')
        } else {
          this.salvando = true
          if (this.form.codPessoa) { // ATUALIZAR DADOS AGROINDUSTRIA
            this.alert = false
            this.api.put('/agroindustria/attAgroindustria', this.form)
              .then(response => {
                this.salvando = false
                if (response.data.error) {
                  let erros = ''
                  response.data.message.forEach((el) => {
                    erros += el + '<br/>'
                  })
                  this.Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Corrija os erros abaixo:',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    html: erros,
                  })
                } else {
                  this.Swal.fire('Sucesso', 'Cadastro Realizado', 'success')
                  this.$router.push({ name: 'Listar Agroindustrias' })
                }
              }).catch(error => {
                this.salvando = false
                this.Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Atenção:',
                  icon: 'warning',
                  html: error,
                })
              })
          } else { // CRIAR NOVA AGROINDUSTRIA
            console.log(this.form)
            this.api.post('/agroindustria/createAgroindustria', this.form, this.primeiroAcesso)
              .then(response => {
                this.salvando = false
                if (response.data.error) {
                  let erros = ''
                  response.data.message.forEach((el) => {
                    erros += el + '<br/>'
                  })
                  this.Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Corrija os erros abaixo:',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    html: erros,
                  })
                } else {
                  this.Swal.fire('Sucesso', 'Cadastro Realizado.', 'success')
                  this.$router.push({ name: 'Listar Agroindustrias' })
                }
              }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                this.salvando = false
                this.Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Atenção:',
                  icon: 'warning',
                  html: error + '<br/>Algo de errado não está certo.',
                })
              })
          }
        }
      },
      formDados () {
        this.api('/agroindustria/', {
          params: {
            CodPessoa: this.form.codPessoa,
          },
        })
          .then(response => {
            this.form.nomeFantasia = response.data[0].NomeFantasia
            this.form.razaoSocial = response.data[0].RazaoSocial
            this.form.porte = response.data[0].Porte
            this.form.cnpj = response.data[0].Cnpj
            this.form.estado = response.data[0].estado
            this.form.cidade = response.data[0].cidade
            this.form.logradouro = response.data[0].Logradouro
            this.form.numero = response.data[0].Numero
            this.form.bairro = response.data[0].Bairro
            this.form.cep = response.data[0].Cep
            this.form.complemento = response.data[0].Complemento
            this.form.telRes = response.data[0].TelRes
            this.form.telCel = response.data[0].TelCel
            this.form.email = response.data[0].email
            this.loadEstadoEdit(response.data[0].estado, response.data[0].cidade)
          }).catch(error => {
            this.message = error
            // console.log(this.message)
          })
      },
      formTelefone (TelRes) {
        for (let i = 0; i < TelRes.length; i++) {
          switch (TelRes[i].CodTipoTelefone) {
            case '1':
              this.form.telCel = TelRes[i].DDD ? '' + TelRes[i].DDD + TelRes[i].Numero : null
              break
            case '2':
              this.form.telCome = TelRes[i].DDD ? '' + TelRes[i].DDD + TelRes[i].Numero : null
              break
            default:
              this.form.telReca = TelRes[i].DDD ? '' + TelRes[i].DDD + TelRes[i].Numero : null
              break
          }
        }
      },
      loadEstado () {
        this.api('/estado').then(response => {
          // console.log(this.response.data.estado)     //HERE'S WHERE THE ISSUE OCCURS
          this.estado = response.data.estado
          console.log(this.estado)
        }).catch(error => {
          this.message = error
          // console.log(this.message)
        })
      },
      loadCidade (CodEstado) {
        this.loadingCidades = true
        this.api('/cidade', {
          params: {
            CodEstado: CodEstado,
          },
        })
          .then(response => {
            this.cidade = response.data.cidade
            this.disableCidade = false
            this.loadingCidades = false
            // console.log(this.cidade)
          }).catch(error => {
            this.message = error
          // console.log(this.message)
          })
      },
      loadEstadoEdit (CodEstado, CodCidade) {
        this.api('/estado').then(response => {
          this.estado = response.data.estado
          this.form.estado = CodEstado
          // this.form.estado = this.form.estado[CodEstado - 1]
          this.loadCidadeEdit(CodCidade)
          // console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
          this.message = error
          // console.log(this.message)
        })
      },
      loadCidadeEdit (CodCidade) {
        this.api('/cidade', {
          params: {
            CodEstado: this.form.estado,
          },
        }).then(response => {
          this.cidade = response.data.cidade
          this.form.cidade = CodCidade
          this.disableCidade = false
          // this.form.cidade = this.cidade[CodCidade - 1]
        }).catch(error => {
          this.message = error
          // console.log(this.message)
        })
      },
      changeCidade () {
        this.loadCidade(this.form.estado)
        // console.log(this.company.estado)
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the form is not a "placeholder". It's initial value of your `v-autocomplete` (`form.estado = 0`)

Reason you see `[object Object]` is because of property names `item-text="Nome" item-value="CodCidade"` on `v-autocomplete` doesn't match with the initial value of a lookup "table" set in your data `estado: [{ nome: 'Carregando', CodEstado: 0 }]`

Correct: `estado: [{ Nome: 'Carregando', CodEstado: 0 }]` ("Nome" instead of "nome")